# Order receipt of bank transactions

Tags: data-request, finance, bank

I am looking for Pictures of order receipts of bank Transactions.
Optimally for Instruments like Shares, Options or funds.

Would be optimal if data Quality is good enough to be processable by ocr engines.

Answer (score 1):

This type of data is generated by financial institutions and is usually protected and not made available to the public.

> There is a d[ataset](https://github.com/awesomedata/awesome-public-datasets/issues/234), that has real transactions but it doesn't have any label for fraud detection. It is Berka dataset available as part of PKDD'99 Discovery Challenge.
> It is real anonymized data from the Czech bank.

- [http://sorry.vse.cz/~berka/challenge/pkdd1999/data_berka.zip](http://sorry.vse.cz/%7Eberka/challenge/pkdd1999/data_berka.zip)
- http://lisp.vse.cz/pkdd99/berka.htm

It seems the link for data description doesn't work anymore, so please use this link from WebArchive:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20161019192412/http://lisp.vse.cz/pkdd99/berka.htm

Python Notebooks that did some analysis on the data that might be helpful:

- https://github.com/justinng1/berka

[Follow this thread](https://github.com/awesomedata/awesome-public-datasets/issues/234)

---

[Santander Customer Transaction Prediction](https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-customer-transaction-prediction/data)

You can find more at Kaggle Datasets